Composition of a $L^2$ function with a $C^1$ monotone function (with some additional conditions) is again $L^2$
I don't know why this problem is giving me so much trouble but for whatever reason I cannot do this, maybe it's just too late in the day. Take $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open and bounded, $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be in $L^2(U)$ and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be monotone increasing and differentiable ($C^1$), what conditions do I need on $g$ for $g(f(z))$ to be again in $L^2(U)$? Of course if $g$ is bounded this is easy, if it is $O(|x|)$ then that also works.
The specific condition that I have in mind is as follows, let $G$ be an antiderivative of $g$, suppose $G(f(z))$ is $L^2(U)$, then would this suffice?
Heuristically, $g$ is of order lesser than or equal to $G$, like if $G=O(|x|^n)$ then $g=O(|x^{n-1}|)$. The divergence of $\|g(f(x))\|_2$ can only happen in the case that $f$ has a singularity/pole, with $g(f(x))$  having a pole at the same place of an even higher order (since we are on a bounded domain). Having the condition that $G(f(x))$ is $L^2$ means that wherever $g(f(x))$ has a pole, $G(f(x))$ will as well of higher order, so intuitively we can control whether or not $g(f(x))$ diverges by $G(f(x))$.
For whatever reason I cannot think of counterexamples or a formalize a proof. Which honestly might just be a sign that I need to get dinner and go to sleep.

You need to be careful on the definition of just being differentiable. Do you assume g' to be continuous?

Yes I suppose, let $g$ be differentiable with continuous first derivative.

If $g(x) \ne O(|x|)$, then I claim there is $f \in L^2(U)$ such that $g\circ f$ is not in $L^2(U)$.
The statement $g(x) \ne O(|x|)$ is equivalent to:
for every $N, M > 0$ there is $x$ with $|x| > N$ and $|g(x)| > M |x|$. Let $U_n$ be a sequence of
disjoint nonempty open subsets of $U$, $m_n$ the measure of $U_n$.  Take $x_n$ so $|x_n| > 1/(n \sqrt{m_n})$ and
$|g(x_n)| > n |x_n| > 1/\sqrt{m_n}$.
Let $V_n$ be a subset of $U_n$ with measure $1/(n |x_n|)^2$ (note that this $< m_n$, so such a subset exists).  We define $$ f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n I_{V_n}$$ where
$I_{V_n}$ is the indicator function of $V_n$.
Then $$\int |f(x)|^2 \,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(V_n) |x_n|^2
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2 < \infty$$ so $f \in L^2$.  But
$$\int |g(f(x))|^2 \, dx > \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(V_n) g(x_n)^2 > \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 = \infty$$ so $g \circ f \notin L^2(U)$.

Ok so this resolves the general case, but I believe this doesn’t resolve the condition I’m looking for, since in this case any antiderivative of $g$, say $G$, will give $G(f(x))\not\in L^2(U)$.

Since by differentiable you mean $C^1$ it suffices to assume $g$ to be Lipschitz: there is a $L>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|\le L|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$.
Therefore $|g(f(x))|\le L|f(x)|+|g(0)|$ hence
$$\int|g(f(x))|^2dx\le2\int (L^2|f(x)|^2+|g(0)|^2)dx\le2 L^2\|f\|_{L^2}^2+2|g(0)|^2m(U)<\infty.$$

Okay sorry maybe another clarification is in order. I mean $C^1$ as in continuous with continuous derivative. This does not imply Lipschitz, only locally Lipschitz, since the derivative need not be bounded.
